# laravel installation error for new project

Tags: laravel, installation

I want to install laravel for a brand new project, but it gives me the following error when I run this command in command line:

```
composer create project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

> UnexpectedValueException could not parse version constraint blog, invalid version string 'blog'

[image]

What could be the reason for this, and how to fix it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation .

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is wrong, you forgot `-` between create project

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: each time I want to create new project I should download all those packages,can i keep copy of these downloaded files and use them for other projects as well ?

Comment: Yes, you can keep a copy of the project.

Comment: It is bizarre how a simple typo generates such a strange error message.